# AG-Grid: 'Virtual list has not been created' Error on First Filter Render when using keyCreator

Tags: filter, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am encountering an issue with AG-Grid's filtering functionality. Specifically, the error "Virtual list has not been created" appears when I open a filter for the first time after rendering the grid. However, if I open a filter on another column and then revisit the original column, the filter renders correctly with all values listed.

Here's a screenshot and gif illustrating the error during the first filter render: [Error on first filter render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgTVe.png)

['Virtual list has not been created' Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U50po.gif)

The issue seems to be related to the `keyCreator` function within `filterParams`. When I remove `keyCreator`, the error no longer appears, but I need this function because the value being filtered is an object. Here's the relevant part of my column definition:

```
filterParams: {
          keyCreator: (params: KeyCreatorParams) => params.value?.label,
          valueFormatter: (params: ValueFormatterParams) => params.value?.label,
          buttons: ['clear'],
        } as ISetFilterParams,
```

I am looking for insights into what might be causing this problem and how to resolve it.

Is there a specific aspect of the keyCreator implementation that could lead to this error? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

React 18.2.0
Ag-grid version: 31.0.0.
Tested on updated browsers.

I have tried different ways of writing the keyCreator function, but I still get the same error. I also tried removing other parts of my AG-Grid code to see if something else was causing the problem. But, the error only goes away when I take out the keyCreator part.

I thought that changing the keyCreator or other parts of the AG-Grid code would fix the error. I was hoping to get the filter to work right the first time I open it. The error keeps happening as long as keyCreator is there, which I didn't expect. It looks like the problem is really about how the keyCreator works in AG-Grid.